# Strongloop/Loopback mongodb query is working on local server but not on Heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku, loopbackjs, strongloop

In the following code snippet i am fetching all records from Installation of multiple userIds using **inq** operator of loopback. Code is working fine on local server but not on Heroku, it is returning empty result while record is available in collection.

```
module.exports = function(Installation) {
    Installation.getDeviceToken = function(userIds, callback) {
        if(!Array.isArray(userIds)) {
            var userIds = new Array(userIds);
        }
        console.log(userIds);
        Installation.find({
            where: { 
                userId: {inq: userIds} 
            },
            scope: {
              fields: {deviceToken: true}
            }
        }).then(function(result){
            var deviceTokens = [];
            console.log(result);
            var stringifiedTokens = JSON.stringify(result);
            var tokensObject = JSON.parse(stringifiedTokens);
            tokensObject.forEach(function(token) {
                deviceTokens.push(token.deviceToken);
            });
            callback(null, deviceTokens);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Maybe a datasource configuration issue? Hard to tell without seeing your config files, but this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651567/how-to-configure-strongloop-loopback-mongodb-datasource-for-deployment-to-heroku?rq=1

Comment: @amuramoto, actually other queries are working fine for example it give result if i run **Installation.find({ where { userid:id } })** for single record. Only problem is with **inq** operator on Heroku server.

Comment: I have the same problem using postgres connector on amazon web services.